# Spring Data CrudRepository only returns changed fields when calling save()

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data (version 1.13.9.RELEASE) and have a `CrudRepository` called `myRepository`. I'm calling `myRepository.save(myObject)`, to overwrite an existing instance of `myObject` in the database, and I'm specifying some fields of `myObject` as `null`.

For example:

```
{
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": null,
    "prop3": "val3"
}
```

When I call `myRepository.save(myObject)` and read the return value, all of the fields of `myObject` that I set as `null` are returned as `null` (so `prop2` in this example).

However, the value for `prop2` in the database is NOT `null` after calling `save()` - it still has the previous value before I called `save()`.

This is actually the behavior that I want in this particular situation (to ignore `null` values when calling `myRepository.save()`), but I'd like the return value of `save()` to reflect what is actually in the database after the operation, rather than only returning the updated fields and setting fields specified as `null` to `null` or their default value (such as `false` in the case of a boolean.

Is this the expected behavior of `CrudRepository`'s `save()` behavior?

Comment: Just curious if your database is updating properly?

Comment: There is a chance it's not. I'm using DynamoDB. It's possible it should be setting the fields to `null`.  However, if it's not, I think that the `CrudRepository` should basically be re-querying the database when calling `save()` to return the most up to date values. I'm not sure where it's seeing these values as `null` (since they're not `null` in Dynamo)

Comment: Second question.. are you using Hibernate?

Comment: @PranjalGore Yes I am

Comment: Okay. So you need to first fetch the most up to date object, this attaches the object to persistent state. Second, update the object ( while its still in the persistent state ) and then finally call save.

Comment: I'm also not as familiar with Spring Data or Dynamo but I agree it should not be returning the values from the database unless you explicitly re-query it. I think you should either be calling myRepository.saveAndFlush() or using myRepository.merge()

Answer (score 0):

To understand the problem you need to understand a little bit about Hibernate Object Lifecycle.

The Hibernate Object Lifecycle consist of these states :
 1. Transient State
 2. Persistent State
 3. Detached State etc

When you create a new object, its in the transient state and Hibernate has no means of detection of objects present/created in the transient state.

When you call `save()` `saveOrUpdate()` then the object moves from transient state to persistent state and now Hibernate will start keeping a track of all the changes made to the object (but the object is not yet written in the db).

So in your case, since the object is not in the persistent state, hibernate fails to recognise it and will fire (most likely) an `insert` query. However, if the object was already in the persistent state, hibernate would have known that some fields have modified and hence will fire an `update` query.

That is why you need to make sure the object is in persistent state if you want hibernate to fire an `update` query.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the transaction is not complete yet and all the changes are only within the cache. To force updating you may call `entityManager.flush()` or move all the logic that you need into a separate public method of another Service or Manager and annotate it as `@Transactional`